# How to vertically align text across browsers

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser, vertical-alignment

Please note that I have been through the existing links on this topic and none seem to help in my case.

All suggest a way of how to move the text vertically so that it appears aligned. The problem in my case is that it is already aligned in Chrome, so when I try to align the text for Firefox then it misaligns the text in Chrome.

Please open the following link in Firefox (v12) and Chrome (v19).

> http://jsfiddle.net/UQ4D5/

You will notice that it is shifted towards the top in Firefox but is perfectly aligned in Chrome.

Comment: From experience, some scenarios will be handled differently by rendering engines - notably vertical alignment inside an element with an odd height. On the upside, same scenarios will be handled consistently *within* the browser and the 2px displacement is likely negligible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two properties in your css

```
 display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
```

Check to live demo http://jsfiddle.net/UQ4D5/5/

Comment: This seems to work fine in FF and Chrome. Can you please confirm if it works in IE9+?

Comment: if you check to any properties which run to browser than go this site http://caniuse.com/

Comment: It seems FF has rendering bug. Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/UQ4D5/15/. Notice that as you make the container smaller and the font larger, the error increases. So, I think it is futile to try and address this.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) for prevent small differences in browser rendering models.

And then use [height=line-height](http://dabblet.com/gist/2822826) trick:

```
div {
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**chrome metrics:**
[image]
**firefox metrics:**
[image]

Height is the same in both cases.

Comment: In my actual code I am indeed using reset. Anyway I tired your solution in FF and it is still shifted upwards. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UQ4D5/10/

Comment: i added metrics stats of this 2 browser and it is identical to each other

Comment: Even if you do not use `height` and `line-height` the height will still remain same. In that case it uses the child (text node) to determine its height. Even when the heights are same the vertical position of the text is not. I am not sure how to measure that except for taking screenshot and using a scale.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is based on the Browser default Stylesheets. I recommend you to use a proper [reset Stylesheet](http://bit.ly/M0s6H4) or even [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)