# Cross browser vertical text alignment

Tags: css

Can anyone explain why vertical text alignment is so different between browsers?

See code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <p style="background: grey;   font-size: 400%;">Test text &lArr;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This displays quite differently between Firefox and Internet Explorer.  Is there some css setting I can use to make this the same across all browsers?

Comment: This link could be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793503/how-to-vertically-align-text-across-browsers

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library to normalize their web pages across browsers.

[Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

I have helped you in any way

Comment: Interesting, and might be a good suggestion to include anyway but still doesn't actually make the text align the same in both browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Just Give default style to body tag like below

```
body{padding:0; margin:0; line-height: 1.1;}
```

Comment: Makes a bit of difference but still not rendered at the same vertical position in both browsers.

Comment: Yes, coz firefox and IE took slighlty(just point pixel) more height than chrome due to font differnce.